# Matplotlib loglog plot ,set_xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the code written below, I am trying to get the x tick labels by using the function `get_xticks()` after setting a limit to x axis values which is 1,2. So I was expecting values between 1 to 2 from `get_xticks()`. But instead I am getting set of values `[0.1,1,10,100]`.

I could not understand why it is giving these values. Is it because of loglog plot? If so how this limit is related to the the values that I am getting now?

```
time = [1, 2, 3, 4]
position = [10, 20, 30, 40]

plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.ylabel('Position (km)')
fig = plt.figure(1) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.loglog(time,position)
xlim = [1,2]
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
xlabels = ax.get_xticks()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because the plot is loglog. What you are seeing in the plot is actually one major tick (10^0) and the other 5 are *minor* ticks.

[`ax.get_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks) has an argument `minor=` which will return the minor ticks instead of the major ticks, if set to `True`

```
print(ax.get_xticks())  # returns the major ticks
# [  0.1   1.   10.  100. ]

print(ax.get_xticks(minor=True))  # returns the minor ticks
# [1.2000000000000002, 1.4000000000000001, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
```

Comment: Sorry one more doubt. I am not getting the output that you printed. I am getting something like this -[2.e-01 3.e-01 4.e-01 5.e-01 6.e-01 7.e-01 8.e-01 9.e-01 2.e+00 3.e+00
 4.e+00 5.e+00 6.e+00 7.e+00 8.e+00 9.e+00 2.e+01 3.e+01 4.e+01 5.e+01
 6.e+01 7.e+01 8.e+01 9.e+01 2.e+02 3.e+02 4.e+02 5.e+02 6.e+02 7.e+02
 8.e+02 9.e+02]..!

Comment: Do you get that output with the code in your question, or with your real code?

Comment: Both are same. I am not getting [1.2000000000000002, 1.4000000000000001, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0] when I used print(ax.get_xticks(minor=True)). It is giving the result that i wrote above!